# Function declared in header not accessible in main file

Tags: c, arduino, undefined-reference

I have a file structure as follows:

```
interface.h --> interface.c
      |
      |
effects.h --> effects.c
      |
      |
    main
```

However, functions declared in effects.h are not accessible in main.

Code snippets :

main :

```
#include "interface.h"
#include "effects.h"
void setup()  //Initialize all variables here
{

....
turnoff();
};
```

effects.h :

```
#ifndef EFFECTS
#define EFFECTS
void turnoff();
#endif
```

effects.c :

```
#include "interface.h"
#include "effects.h"
void turnoff()
{
....
};
```

interface.h :

```
#ifndef INTERFACE
#define INTERFACE
....
#endif
```

Error message : ``` In function ``loop':undefined reference to ``turnoff()' ```

The error message doesnt make sense as loop function is empty !

Comment: Is it a linker error ?

Comment: @cnicutar I am using the Arduino IDE. Not compiling or linking manually.

Comment: It's likely you've not configured it correctly to link both files.

Comment: If you copied everything correctly... isn't one of your files in C++? (like, `*.cxx` or `*.cpp` rather than `*.c`?)

Comment: @AntonKovalenko No. Why ? The IDE should handle `C` code correctly.

Comment: Are both interface.c and effects.c part of the compilation?

Comment: @Ganesh Compilation, yes.

Comment: Where is the function `loop` defined? If the function `loop` is inside interface.c, can you please confirm if effects.h is also included in interface.c?

Comment: @Ganesh Its in the main file after setup.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile and link all 3 .c files together. With `gcc` it's as simple as

`gcc main.c interface.c effects.c -o executable_name`

Comment: That's not very relevant. You need to find out how to include all 3 .c files into the project in your IDE or whatever it is, so it invokes the compiler and linker with proper parameters.

Comment: The IDE abstracts away a lot of the stuff. The Arduino build process links the code to quite a few of its libraries and also specifies many parameters. At the moment, I really cant get into that.

Answer (score 1):

I think the IDE wants *.cpp files instead of *.c files.

Anyway you should change the settings under file->preferences to get verbose compiler output. Usually this gives some hints. At least it shows you the temporary directory that contains the files that are ***actually*** compiled. This in turn allows much more precise analysis of the issue.

Comment: i had the same thing happen in arduino. renaming the .c to .cpp fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

From the latest response, I feel that `effects.c` is not part of the compilation. I am not aware of the development environment, but from the available data, this is my observation.

Answer (score 0):

what are the flags you are using?
maybe you need to declare your functions as extern explicitly?

```
extern void turnoff();
```